# Unable to start jenkins in amazon linux 2: start request repeated too quickly

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

```
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Mar 28 10:01:25 ip-172-31-40-247.eu-north-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

Does anyone know the root cause of this?